# React on('languageChanged', isn't working for detecting language change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-translate

I'm quite new to react and I'm searching the best way to detect when user change language. I'm using next translate to translate resources but for some ressource I'm getting from API, I need to change them manually. Here is the way I'm using default ressources:

On page:

```
const { t } = useTranslation("member");
```

That calls:

```
import { I18n } from '.';
export default function useTranslation(defaultNS?: string): I18n;
```

And here is the way language is changed into the picker component:

```
router.replace(router.asPath, undefined, { locale: locale/*, shallow: true*/ });
```

Here are things I've tried so far:
I'm not into a component (it's a jsx page) so I think I cannot use

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) { if (this.props.t !== prevProps.t) { console.log(this.props.i18n.language); } }
```

It gives me a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`

I've tried that too but it

```
import I18n from 'i18n';
i18next.on('languageChanged', function(lng) {})
```

Gives me `TypeError: _next_translate_root_i18n__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...).on is not a function`

Comment: *i18n* != *i18next*. Which library are you using exactly?

Comment: @Bergi : next-translate https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-translate

Comment: Then I'm not sure from where you got `i18next.on('languageChanged', function(lng) {})`.

Comment: Given that *next-translate* uses routing to set the language, you can detect changes to the language in the same way you detect changes to any routing parameter (in this case, `locale`). [The docs](https://github.com/aralroca/next-translate#11-how-to-save-the-user-defined-language) also show using an effect with the `useRouter` hook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useTranslation } from "next-translate";

function MyPage() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Language changed to ${i18n.language}`);
    // Do something here when the language changes
  }, [i18n.language]);

  return <div>{t("hello")}</div>;
}

export default MyPage;
```

using the `useEffect` hook to listen for changes to the `i18n.language` property, which is automatically updated by `next-translate` when the user changes the language. When the language changes, the effect function is called and you can do something in response.

Note that you should include `i18n.language` in the dependency array of `useEffect`. This ensures that the effect function is called every time the language changes.

Comment: Simple and straightforward.                                                                                   +1!